# Azure VM and disk recommendation

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-virtual-machine, postgresql-14

I want to have your recommendation for vm and disk on Azure.
Here is my requirements. And I want to install postgreSQL 14 on it.

**Data location** : /pgdbfiles => 1 Tb

**Internal memory** : => 32 Gb

**Number vcpu’s** : => 16

**Filesystem for log shipping wal files** =>  100 Gb

**OS** => Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5

Comment: Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes

Comment: Impossible to answer because we have no idea what the load will be, data model, query efficiency, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the VM recommended for your requirement is **F16s_v2**

Data location disk: a **Premium SSD LRS of 1024 GiB** is recommended, but it will depend on how high the IOPS for the database is.

Filesystem for log shipping wal files: This could be an **Standard HDD of 128 GiB**, again it will depend on the IOPS for that disk.

You can use **Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5 (LVM) - Gen 2** as OS image for the OS.

hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much for your prompt response. I have one more question about Red Hat Enterprise Linux. Do we need to pay extra cost for the licence or it is included in the azure subscription?

Comment: Quoting MS: "Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) images are available in Azure via a pay-as-you-go or bring-your-own-subscription (BYOS) (Red Hat Gold Image) model. "